# How to use Wget to download linked files hosted on domain other that the original request?

Tags: windows, cmd, wget

Let's say we have domain `http://domain.com` and on the root of it we have `index.html`.

In `index.html` there are links to images like:

`<a href="//anotherdomain.com/1.jpg?random=[a random number here]">image name</a>`

I guess that a random number at the end of the URL would not be a problem if I have used RegEx - something like `*.jpg*`.

But how to force Wget to access hyperlinks linking to other domain than the domain from original request?

Comment: See http://superuser.com/questions/341960/how-do-you-use-wget-to-mirror-a-site-1-level-deep-recovering-js-css-resources, you need the -H option (_"--span-hosts
Enable spanning across hosts when doing recursive retrieving."_).

Comment: @CodeCaster Great! :) Can you post it as answer?